# R: Transpose Data from Wide to Long in Dataframe with many column names

Tags: r, data-cleaning, transpose

I have a dataset that reflects responses to practice questions for a small group of people (~30). The dataset is very wide and has data for questions sent every day of the year. For each question that is sent I have data on: 1) the time of the response (ex. "cardiology_1_timestamp), 2) the answer given (ex. "cardiology_1), 3) the correct answer/key (ex. "cardiology_1_key), 4) and an indicator for if the respondent answered the question (ex. "cardiology_1_complete"). The naming convention for all the sets of columns follows this pattern, but the keyword changes. For example "cardiology" could be "nutrition" or "immunology". There are also inconsistent number for each category (cardio has 90, nutrition has 20, etc.), though each question in each category is identified with a sequential integer - but as seen below this integer identifier is not always the column name suffix.

**Have**

| Record_ID | cardiology_1_timestamp | cardiology_1 | cardiology_key_1 | cardiology_1_complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-07-10 12:45:49 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 2019-07-11 21:38:52 | 4 | 4 | 2 |

```r
structure(list(Record_ID = 1:2, cardiology_1_timestamp = c("2019-07-10 12:45:49", "2019-07-11 21:38:52"), cardiology_1 = c(1L, 4L), cardiology_key_1 = c(4L, 4L), cardiology_1_complete = c(2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I would like this data in long format with 1 column each for the characteristics described (timestamp, response given, correct answer, and completed the question) as well as a new column that indicates the question. Going with the present example this would be a new column with a value of "cardiology_1".

**Want**

| Record_ID | Question | Timestamp | Response | Key | Complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cardiology_1 | 2019-07-10 12:45:49 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | cardiology_2 | 2019-07-11 11:20:22 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | cardiology_1 | 2019-07-11 21:38:52 | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | cardiology_2 | 2019-07-12 01:20:46 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

```r
structure(list(Record_ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Question = c("cardiology_1", "cardiology_2", "cardiology_1", "cardiology_2"), Timestamp = c("2019-07-10 12:45:49", "2019-07-11 11:20:22", "2019-07-11 21:38:52", "2019-07-12 01:20:46"), Response = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L), Key = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), Complete = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I am relatively new to R (typically a SAS user) but am trying to get this figured out. I have attempted to utilize 'pivot_longer' but am struggling with how to deal with identifying my original columns by their names and extracting the correct portion for the new "Question" column.

Comment: Could you please share you sample data with `dput()` so it will be copy/pasteable and easy to import?

Comment: And, if I'm interpreting your question correctly, the sample data you share would produce only rows 1 and 3 of the result? Are `cardiology_2_*` columns missing from the input? If so, I would include the set of `cardiology_2_*` columns in the sample input (and let us know if there are more so we can make sure any answer generalizes up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# first, we clean the column names. We do this because most of the other columns are of the form area_questionnumber_attribute, and cardiology_1 is not that
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(df), pattern = c("key_(\\d+)" = "\\1_Key", "(?<=\\d$)" = "_Answer", "_c" = "_C", "_t" = "_T"))

# we can then simply call pivot_longer, separating the column names
df |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Record_ID,
    names_to = c("Category", "Question", ".value"),
    names_sep = "_")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  Record_ID Category   Question Timestamp           Answer   Key Complete
      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1         1 cardiology 1        2019-07-10 12:45:49      1     4        2
2         2 cardiology 1        2019-07-11 21:38:52      4     4        2
```

Data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Record_ID = c(1, 2),
  cardiology_1_timestamp = c("2019-07-10 12:45:49", "2019-07-11 21:38:52"),
  cardiology_1 = c(1, 4),
  cardiology_key_1 = c(4, 4),
  cardiology_1_complete = c(2, 2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with some creative renaming (to standardize the pattern, so that `names_pattern=` will work more easily) and then careful use of `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
quux %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~ sub("(_[0-9]+)$", "\\1_response", 
                          sub("_(.*)_([0-9]+)$", "_\\2_\\1", .)) ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Record_ID, names_pattern = "(.*)_([^_]+)$",
               names_to = c("Question", ".value"))
# # A tibble: 2 × 6
#   Record_ID Question     timestamp           response   key complete
#       <int> <chr>        <chr>                  <int> <int>    <int>
# 1         1 cardiology_1 2019-07-10 12:45:49        1     4        2
# 2         2 cardiology_1 2019-07-11 21:38:52        4     4        2
```

Explanation:

- `rename_with` is two steps: the inner `sub(.)` moves the `_1` (and other numbers) to be immediately after `cardiology_` instead of sometimes on the end, sometimes in the middle; the outer `sub(.)` adds `Response` to the column(s) that have no category appended to them (I admit that this is a bit presumptuous and possibly fragile if your dataset is significantly different)
- `pivot_longer` and its `names_pattern=` argument relies on the order of `cardiology_#` followed by the category, and then breaks those categories into individual columns.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Record_ID = 1:2, cardiology_1_timestamp = c("2019-07-10 12:45:49", "2019-07-11 21:38:52"), cardiology_1 = c(1L, 4L), cardiology_key_1 = c(4L, 4L), cardiology_1_complete = c(2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```